# Azure devops organization name taken - have GitHub organization with this name

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have just set up an Azure Devops account and tried to create organizations for the companies I work for. Both names had been taken, which surprised me. We have GitHub organizations with the same names, so need the same names for the Devops pipelines. Is it possible that Azure Devops sees these names as taken because GitHub organizations exist with the same names? If not, is there anyway of finding out who owns the Azure Devops organizations to see if they are active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First

The names don't have to be the same, your GitHub organization and your Azure DevOps organization can each have their own name. You can even connect multiple Azure DevOps organizations to the same GitHub or connect multiple GitHub repositories to a single Azure DevOps.

### Second

There is no relation between Azure DevOps Organization names and GitHub. An org on one won't reserve the name on the other platform or vice versa.

### Third

[You can contact Azure support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&) to have them contact the owners of the organizations. If you are lucky, the organizations are already connected to your AAD, in which case support can reset the owner. If the account is owned by a MSA or a different company, things will be a bit harder.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was under the impression that to integrate a GitHub organization to an Azure Devops organization, the names had to be the same. Is it just that repos need to have the same name as AD pipelines or can even this be relaxed?

Comment: No constraint whatsoever. Any org and any project in Azure DevOps can connect to any org and any repo in GitHub.